# <fb:intl> does not work

Tags: facebook, internationalization

I tried to work with  today. My starting point was here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization. Unfortunately I am not able to register a string with the translation application.

I found two threads indicating that  is still buggy and not worth working on - last entries on both a few month old:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=70655
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11448

Anybody has some more information on this? A working sample would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, an annoying bug I have come up against too. No solution yet. It seems to only work for fbml canvas apps.

Comment: yes very annoying. I reopened it in the new bug system, you find it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/205600089506532?browse=search_4e81dffa0591d6d43966739

Answer (score 1):

Registering strings works with [intl.uploadNativeStrings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/intl.uploadNativeStrings/). You can enter your strings directly on that page, for exampe: enter in the native_string field: [{text: "some string", desc: "a description"}]
Then click Call Method

After registering, I can translate the strings in the Translations App.

But anyway, the strings in my Iframe App are still not translated. Is use

```
<fb:intl>some string</fb:intl>
```

tags in my app and call

```
FB.init({
    appId   : '$appid',
    status  : true, // check login status
    cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
});
```

...on the script //connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js

but my strings are never translated. Any further help on this?